# Where can I find basic geometry routines?

Tags: delphi

Where can I find geometry algorithms, which can answer "simple" question like if there is two line intersection, if a point is inside polygon and so on.

I was good at math, but this topic for me is a little outdated. But to my surprise I can not find suitable pack of routines, which solves these problems.

Comment: On Windows you can use `PtInRegion`. Are for whether or not two lines intersect, you need to compare their slopes. If they differ the lines intersect. If the slopes are the same they are parallel. Then they intersect if they are on top of each other. I'm assuming 2D geometry.

Comment: there are couples of ways to do it theoretically... I have found finally fastGEO.pas, what comprises many many routines I desire, but I am afraid everything requires a little study.... eh...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Does [FastGEO](http://www.partow.net/projects/fastgeo/index.html) suit your needs?

The abstract for the project is

> FastGEO is a library written in Delphi that contains a wide range of
>   highly optimized vector based geometrical algorithms and routines for
>   many different types of geometrical operations such as geometrical
>   primitives and predicates, hull construction and triangulation,
>   clipping, rotations and projections.

Answer (score 4):

The SDL suite has this kind of stuff.  http://www.lohninger.com/sdlindex.html.  We use a lot of their library and have been quite happy with it (and their support).

I believe they have a free version.

T.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to visit the following sites :

- [efg's Computer Lab](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/index.html).
- [Freeware Delphi Components & Utilities](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/) by Angus Johnson.

I hope these will help you.